# Excel VBA with Windows Media Player: Runtime error while getting video timecode

Tags: vba, excel, windows-media-player

I've added a Windows Media Player ActiveX control (WMPlayer2) and two command buttons, viz, cmd_PlayVideo and cmd_GetTimeCode on an Excel sheet. I would like to play a video in Windows Media Player and capture the timecode of the video as and when I click the cmd_GetTimeCode button while the video is being played.

Since the '**currentPositionTimecode**' property is available in IWMPControls3 interface, I've cast the return value from WMPlayer2.controls to the IWMPControls3 interface. However, the line 'MsgBox controls.currentPositionTimecode' throws:

> run-time error 430: "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface."

The other properties of the IWMPControls3 interface such as audioLanguageCount, currentAudioLanguage, currentItem, controls.getAudioLanguageID, getLanguageName, 
and getAudioLanguageDescription work fine.

How can I get the timecode of the video?

Here is my code in 2 buttons.

```
Private Sub cmd_PlayVideo_Click()

MsgBox Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
WMPlayer2.URL = Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub cmd_GetTimeCode_Click()

Dim controls As WMPLib.IWMPControls3
Dim Media As WMPLib.IWMPMedia
Set controls = WMPlayer2.controls

MsgBox controls.audioLanguageCount
MsgBox controls.currentAudioLanguage
If controls.isAvailable("currentItem") Then
    Set Media = controls.currentItem
    MsgBox Media.durationString
    MsgBox Media.Name
    MsgBox Media.SourceUrl
End If

MsgBox controls.getAudioLanguageID(1)
MsgBox controls.getLanguageName(1)
MsgBox controls.getAudioLanguageDescription(1)
MsgBox controls.currentPositionTimecode

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed that reading the **currentPositionTimecode** parameter only throws the error once the media starts playing. That is, it appears that it reads the timecode position without errors only when the media position is reset to zero (e.g.[00000]00:00:00). I suspect that there must be a flag to enable this (like CanScan?) or perhaps the media doesn't support SMPTE timecode. I'm still researching.